# Unexpected value of "this" in Typescript

Tags: typescript, this

I'm following a [Phaser tutorial](http://www.lessmilk.com/tutorial/flappy-bird-phaser-1) to make a Flappy Bird clone. Inside of the `create` method though, the value of `this` is changing from the `FlappyClone` object:

[image]

to another object containing a ton of `Phaser` stuff:

[image: Second this screenshot]

This is causing the call to `this.createBird` to fail, since the `this` value inside of `create` doesn't have a `createBird` method.

Why is `this` changing? Since `create` is a class method, shouldn't `this` refer to the class instance?

And it's likely not that Phaser is calling the method with a different object, since [this](http://phaser.io/tutorials/how-to-use-phaser-with-typescript) tutorial shows `this` being used inside of the method, and referring to instance members.

Full code (app.ts):

```
class FlappyClone {
    private GAME_WIDTH: number = 800;
    private GAME_HEIGHT: number = 600;

    private game: Phaser.Game;
    private bird: Phaser.Sprite;

    private startState = { preload: this.preload, create: this.create, update: this.update };

    constructor() {
        this.game = new Phaser.Game(this.GAME_WIDTH, this.GAME_HEIGHT, Phaser.AUTO, "content", this.startState);

        this.game.state.add('start', this.startState, true);
    }

    preload() {
        this.game.load.image('bird', 'assets/bird.png');
        this.game.load.image('pipePiece', 'assets/pipe.png');

        this.game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
    }

    create() {
        this.bird = this.createBird(this.game.world.centerX, this.game.world.centerY);

        let spaceBar = this.game.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Keyboard.SPACEBAR);
        spaceBar.onDown.add(() => {
            FlappyClone.makeJump(this.bird, 500);
        }, this);


    }

    update() {
        if (this.bird.x < 0 || this.bird.y > this.GAME_HEIGHT) {
            this.restartGame();
        }
    }



    /*private createPipePiece(): Phaser.Spirit {
        var pipePiece = this.game.add.sprite(this.game.
    }*/

    private createBird(x, y): Phaser.Sprite {
        var bird = this.game.add.sprite(x, y, 'bird');
        this.game.physics.enable(bird);
        bird.body.gravity.y = 500;

        return bird;
    }

    private restartGame() {
        this.game.state.start('start');
    }

    private static makeJump(sprite: Phaser.Sprite, velocity: number) {
        sprite.body.velocity.y = -velocity;
    }

}

window.onload = () => {

    var game = new FlappyClone();

};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The Problem

You have the classic JavaScript problem known as the *incorrect `this` context*.
The [`this` keyword in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) behaves differently than in does in other languages like C# and Java.

Specifically, these references are causing a lost `this` context:

```
private startState = { preload: this.preload, create: this.create, update: this.update };
```

#### How `this` works

The `this` keyword, in a function, is determined as follows:
 * If the function was created through a call to `.bind`, the `this` value is the argument provided to `bind`
 * If the function was *invoked* through a method call, e.g. `expr.func(args)`, then `this` is `expr`
 * Otherwise
   * If the code is in [*strict mode*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), `this` is `undefined`
   * Otherwise, `this` is `window` (in a browser)

Let's look at how this works in practice:

```
class Foo {
    value = 10;
    doSomething() {
        // Prints 'undefined', not '10'
        console.log(this.value);
    }
}
let f = new Foo();
window.setTimeout(f.doSomething, 100);
```

This code will print `undefined` (or, in strict mode, throw an exception).
This is because we ended up in the last branch of the decision tree above.
The `doSomething` function was invoked, the function wasn't a result of a `bind` call, and it wasn't invoked in a method syntax position.

We can't see the code for `setTimeout` to see what its invocation looks like, but we don't need to.
Something to realize is that all `doSomething` methods point to *the same function object*.
In other words:

```
let f1 = new Foo();
let f2 = new Foo();
// 'true'
console.log(f1.doSomething === f2.doSomething);
```

We know that `setTimeout` can only see the function we passed it, so when it invokes that function,
  there's no way for it to know which `this` to provide.
The `this` context has been lost due to our *referencing* the method without *invoking* it.

#### The Red Flag

Once you know about `this` problems, they're easy to spot:

```
class Foo {
    value = 10;
    method1() {
        doSomething(this.method2); // DANGER, method reference without invocation
    }   
    method2() {
        console.log(this.value);
    }
}
```

### The Solution

You have a few options here, each with its own trade-offs.
The best option depends on how often the method in question is invoked from differing call sites.

#### Arrow Function in Class Definition

Instead of using the normal method syntax, use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to initialize a per-instance member.

```
class DemonstrateScopingProblems {
    private status = "blah";

    public run = () => {
        // OK
        console.log(this.status);
    }
}
let d = new DemonstrateScopingProblems();
window.setTimeout(d.run); // OK
```

- Good/bad: This creates an additional closure per method per instance of your class. If this method is usually only used in regular method calls, this is overkill. However, if it's used a lot in callback positions, it's more efficient for the class instance to capture the `this` context instead of each call site creating a new closure upon invoke.
- Good: Impossible for external callers to forget to handle `this` context
- Good: Typesafe in TypeScript
- Good: No extra work if the function has parameters
- Bad: Derived classes can't call base class methods written this way using `super.`
- Bad: The exact semantics of which methods are "pre-bound" and which aren't create an additional non-typesafe contract between your class and its consumers.

#### Function Expression at Reference Site

Shown here with some dummy parameters for explanatory reasons:

```
class DemonstrateScopingProblems {
    private status = "blah";

    public something() {
        console.log(this.status);
    }

    public run(x: any, y: any) {
        // OK
        console.log(this.status + ': ' + x + ',' + y);
    }
}
let d = new DemonstrateScopingProblems();
// With parameters
someCallback((n, m) => d.run(n, m));
// Without parameters
window.setTimeout(() => d.something(), 100);
```

- Good/bad: Opposite memory/performance trade-off compared to the first method
- Good: In TypeScript, this has 100% type safety
- Good: Works in ECMAScript 3
- Good: You only have to type the instance name once
- Bad: You'll have to type the parameters twice
- Bad: Doesn't easily work with variadic parameters

Comment: This is copied from elsewhere. I read this not 10 minutes ago.

Comment: Indeed, it's from one of my answers to another question where someone had an identical problem. I can close this question as duplicate if you like, though.

Comment: Well, you solved it, so I'll accept it. Really only the part before "How `this` works" is needed though. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> shouldn't this refer to the class instance

No. This is JavaScript. `this` is called the *calling context* and is driven by the *caller*.

## More

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvocUcbCupA

## Quick fix

Use an arrow function for all your class methods :

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html